# Why macro is running perfect on one computer but on the other is not?

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a macro that works perfect on my computer but on the other it is not, and I have no idea why... It is simple macro that copy worksheet from one workbook to the other.

I'm getting error 9 (out of range) on  this line `Set wbk1 =  Workbooks("発注残マクロ")`

Is this because of different excel versions?

```
Sub CopySheet()
    Dim wbk1 As Workbook, wbk2 As Workbook

    'Workbooks("発注残マクロ").Activate

    Set wbk1 =  Workbooks("発注残マクロ")
    Set wbk2 = Workbooks("ocs680j")

    'シートの名前を記入
    wbk2.Worksheets("ocs680j").Copy After:=wbk1.Sheets(wbk1.Sheets.Count)
    wbk2.Saved = True
    wbk2.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
End Sub
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: `発注残マクロ` would have to be accessible and open on the other computer.

Comment: @ScottCraner `発注残マクロ` is accessible and open on the other computer. It is just a part of a macro that at first open that file and the copy that one specific sheet

Comment: Does it include the file type extension.  For example in English we would need the `.xlsx` also.

Comment: @ScottCraner `発注残マクロ` file is a macro that opens another file `ocs680j` and copy a sheet from that file. so it will be something like `copy sheet from wbk2 and paste it to wbk1` It seems like it can't see the origin  file `発注残マクロ` after opening the other....

Comment: "Hide extensions for known file types" is a setting in Windows Explorer - that can affect behavior in Excel, where if the option is checked "MyFile" would be a valid workbook name, but on a PC with that option unchecked the name would need to be "MyFile.xlsx".  The full name (with extension included) *always* works regardless of the Explorer setting.

Comment: Look into language settings on the other computer, both the languages the computer understands the that VBA uses. VBA doesn't naturally understand Japanese. However, you appear mistaken: "発注残マクロ" is the name of a workbook from which the extension is missing, as @Scott Craner has pointed out. Therefore it is not a macro. Print a list of the open workbooks to the Immediate pane and see by which name Excel refers to this workbook.

Comment: Move the line `Set wbk2 = Workbooks("ocs680j")` above the line currently erroring - does that line now error ?

Comment: @ScottCraner adding file extensions solved the problem! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ScottCraner suggested adding extensions helped solve the problem.

```
Sub CopySheet()
    Dim wbk1 As Workbook, wbk2 As Workbook

    'Workbooks("発注残マクロ.xlsx").Activate

    Set wbk1 =  Workbooks("発注残マクロ.xlsx")
    Set wbk2 = Workbooks("ocs680j.xlsx")

    'シートの名前を記入
    wbk2.Worksheets("ocs680j.xlsx").Copy After:=wbk1.Sheets(wbk1.Sheets.Count)
    wbk2.Saved = True
    wbk2.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
End Sub
```